# boost::spirit::qi

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-spirit

Consider the following code: (Boost.Spirit 2.5.1)

```
qi::parse(str.begin(), str.end(), (+qi::alpha)[[](const string& s){cout << s<< '\n';}]
                                    >> (*(qi::char_(',') | qi::char_('\'')))
                                    >> qi::uint_[[](int integer){cout << integer << '\n';}]);
```

The `[[](int integer){cout << integer << '\n';}]` works, but the analogous code for `+qi::alpha` doesn't.

How can I correct the code?

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it? What errors are you getting? Or is it simply not printing anything?

Comment: I'm not sure if I should post very long lines of errors.

Comment: @user5262: I'm absolutely positive that you must.

Answer (score 6):

<strike>C++0x/C++11 lambdas aren't yet supported by Boost Spirit<sup>1</sup></strike>
**Edit** Apparently support improved (I tested with an older boost version earlier today). Using Boost 1_48 and g++ 4.6.1 now, the following appears to just_work. Yay!

#### `qi::as_string[]`

I think will want to know about `qi::as_string` to get the exposed attribute as 
`std::string` instead of the default `std::vector<CharT>`:

```
    qi::parse(str.begin(), str.end(),
        qi::as_string [ +qi::alpha ] 
        [
            [](const std::string&){std::cout << s << '\n';}
        ]
        >> (*(qi::char_(',') | qi::char_('\'')))
        >> qi::uint_
        [
            [](int integer){std::cout << integer << '\n';}
        ]);
```

But in my opinion the syntax isn't very friendly. Instead, I'd prefer phoenixV2:

```
    qi::parse(str.begin(), str.end(),
        qi::as_string [ +qi::alpha ] [ std::cout << _1 << '\n' ]
        >> (*(qi::char_(',') | qi::char_('\'')))
        >> qi::uint_ [ std::cout << _1 << '\n' ]);
```

That's already a lot shorter and less cryptic syntactically. Have a look at

- using functions/functors as semantic actions: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/semantic_actions.html

A somewhat contrived example showing some of these in action, PLUS passing attribute references directly into the `parse` function:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

bool reverse(std::string& value)
{
    std::reverse(value.begin(), value.end());
    return true; // false makes the parsing fail
}

int main()
{
    std::string str("sometext,123");

    auto f(str.begin()), l(str.end());

    std::string s;
    unsigned int i;

    qi::parse(f,l,
            qi::as_string [ +qi::alpha ] [ reverse ]
            >> qi::omit [ *qi::char_(",\'") ]
            >> qi::uint_,

            s, i);

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Outputs:

```
txetemos
123
```

<sup>1</sup> PhoenixV3 might have some support for that in 1_48 (haven't checked); You'd want to

```
 #define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
 #define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
```

See e.g. http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Boost-Spirit-Phoenix-V3-An-Overview-td3583792.html

Comment: Lambdas obviously work fine, since the OP's `int` lambda works. As Cubbi correctly noted, the problem is that the synthesized attribute of `+qi::alpha` is `std::vector<char>`, not `std::string`. The conversion from one to the other is done implicitly for non-terminals, but not for semantic actions.

Comment: @ildjarn: You're right; things have changed. Have updated my answer. I knew about that conversion, I think the advice to use qi::as_string is also valuable. (_FWIW I linked to the rememberd thread where I had originally learned the information about the extra lambda parameters in the other comment; I can now remember to forget about that, at least on gcc :)_)

Comment: I agree, `qi::as_string` + unary lambda is a clean solution. +1 for your edit. :-]

Answer (score 5):

Your code gives me the following compiler error, skipping some bits

```
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/action_dispatch.hpp:142:13:
error: no matching function for call to
‘action_dispatch<>::do_call(
    const main()::<lambda(const string&)>&,
    action_dispatch<>::fwd_tag<std::vector<char>>,
...
```

which boils down to that the argument passed to your lambda is `vector<char>`, not `string`

So, replace `string` with `vector<char>`:

```
(+qi::alpha)[[](const std::vector<char>& s) {
      cout << std::string(s.begin(), s.end()) << '\n';
}]
```

Comment: Why -1? It compiles and runs with g++ 4.6.2 / boost 1.47.0

Comment: To my surprise this appears to be **a** (!) correct answer. However, `qi::as_string[]` and/or Phoenix are much more natural and idiomatic solutions. FWIW, I based my answer on ready knowledge (see this [Spirit-general list reply by Hartmut Kaiser](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Using-C-0x-well-C-11-lambdas-with-Spirit-Qi-tp3425625p3426036.html) and the followup by [Joel de Guzman, too: `Without phoenix, you are on your 
own to extract all that information from the context. Fiddly!`](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Using-C-0x-well-C-11-lambdas-with-Spirit-Qi-tp3425625p3426726.html) )

Comment: @sehe Indeed, `to_string` is better. I was mostly posting to show how to process the "very long lines of error"

Comment: @Cubbi: a very good point. Let me +1 you for that :) It is actually what I sometimes do at the user-list too (e.g. to point out the explanatory comments at the various points where grammars fail to compile within Spirit library; often they spell out where the problem is at).